# Struggling with saving data to database in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am just starting to learn C# & ASP.NET MVC framework and I am trying to build a shopping cart functionality. This is my (add to cart method) that I think should work but does not. It adds an item to the cart but whenever I add another item the previous one is gone. Do anyone know why my database saving is not working? Am I using the context the right way?

```
namespace e_commerse.Controllers
{
    public class ShoppingcartController : Controller
    {
            private ProductDBContext db = new ProductDBContext();

            [Authorize]
            public ActionResult addToCart(int ID)
            {
                Product product = db.Products.Find(ID);

                if (product == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }

                var userId =  User.Identity.GetUserId();

                IEnumerable<ShoppingCart> shoppingcarts = 
                    from cart in db.Shoppingcarts
                    where cart.userID == userId
                    select cart;

                if (!shoppingcarts.Any())
                {
                    var newShoppingcart = new ShoppingCart();
                    newShoppingcart.products = new List<Product>();
                    newShoppingcart.products.Add(product);
                    newShoppingcart.userID = userId;
                    db.Shoppingcarts.Add(newShoppingcart);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return View("Index", newShoppingcart);
                }

                var shoppingcart = shoppingcarts.First();

                if (shoppingcart.products == null)
                {
                    shoppingcart.products = new List<Product>();
                }

                shoppingcart.products.Add(product);
                shoppingcart.userID = userId;
                db.SaveChanges();

                return View("Index", shoppingcart);
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    db.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
        }

        public class ProductDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
            public DbSet<ShoppingCart> Shoppingcarts { get; set; }
        }

        public class ShoppingCart
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public String userID { get; set; }
            public List<Product> products { get; set; }
        }

        public class Product
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public String title { get; set; }
            public String description { get; set; }
            public decimal price { get; set; }
            public String imagepath { get; set; }
            public Type type { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Every help is deeply appreciated and excuse my noob code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fetching `ShoppingCart` from db it dosen't fetch products list. Your condition is always true:

```
if (shoppingcart.products == null) // is always true
```

So `ShoppingCart.products` is always null, you create `new List<Product>()` and add one product to it. Thats why you have only one product in `ShoppingCart.products` list. Because old list is replaced by new with only  one item.

You have to load previously saved products befor you add new one. You can use [EF lazy-loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy). In your example you can add virtual keyword to `products` property to load it form db when needed:

```
...
public virtual List<Product> products { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do not quite understand. could you put the code in some context?

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm! thank you so much!:) And tnx to everyone for helping!

Answer (score 2):

I think that problem is with below:

```
shoppingcart.products.Add(product);
shoppingcart.userID = userId;
db.SaveChanges();
```

you are adding items to the local variable, not the context. You should change you code to the following:

```
var newShoppingcart = new ShoppingCart();
newShoppingcart.products.Add(product);
newShoppingcart.userID = userId;
db.Shoppingcarts.Add(newShoppingcart);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Just like you did above in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same record every time. Your statement (observation)

> It adds an item to the cart but whenever i add another item the
>   previous one is gone

is not completely true, because your saving the same product again and again. Check your code, you find the product as

```
Product product = db.Products.Find(ID);
```

and finally at bottom, you save that same product again

```
    ......
    ......
    shoppingcart.products.Add(product);
    shoppingcart.userID = userId;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("Index", shoppingcart);
}
```

You are doing no change. If an object has same 'Id' then it will overwrite the existing with same 'Id'.